# REGEX not working for mysql for replacing comma separated ids

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I know my database is not normalized but in my case, It is not possible to normalize the data as each user has different access level with access rights, everytime I modify something and I need to delete the rows and insert back so I went for comma-separated values, here the issue is if I remove a particular group, regex doesn't work, it throws me an error..am using php and the error goes like this

```
FUNCTION database_name.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist
```

Table structure

```
allowed_group_ids
+----------------+
12345,34345,55454
```

My query, say for example `$delete_id` is `12345` or say `55454`, I only pass one ID at a time and the id's has no space in between and it's a text field

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = TRIM(BOTH ',' 
FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '(,(\s)?)?$detele_id', '')) 
WHERE system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
```

So what's wrong in here?

Comment: W.r.t. the php error you should call REGEXP_REPLACE without the DB name or look if you function has a different name.

Comment: @Mr.Radical where do you see the db name in here?

Comment: Your error is "database_name.REGEXP_REPLACE". Before the dot you have database_name. I think that your function is called "REGEXP_REPLACE" and not "database_name.REGEXP_REPLACE".

Comment: that is returned by php error

Comment: Could you post your code and an example from your database.

Comment: @Mr.Radical Its already there bro

Comment: I mean something will initiate you query. Let say you want to print this to the screen. Then you would use something like <? PHP echo REGEXP_REPLACE(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as regexp_replace in MySQL.

You could perform this query using regular replace:

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = 
    trim(BOTH ',' FROM 
        replace(
            replace(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_id',','),
            ',,',
            ','
        )
    )
WHERE system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
```

This first removes the ID, and removes any doubled-up commas, then removes any commas at the start/end of the string. This should be sufficient but you can add another replace to remove whitespace if necessary.

Update: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47cf6/1) shows the query in action

Comment: I assume he has created his own function called REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: Well, you know what they say about assumptions... :)

Comment: @dwurf Am using this but in a different way `UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = REPLACE(REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$detele_group_id,', ''), ',$detele_group_id', '')`, is it fine?

Comment: Nope, you missed the case where there is only one group. Consider `$detele_group_id=1234` and `allowed_group_ids` contains `1234`. In that case `allowed_group_ids` will still contain `1234` after you run your update.